# download files from server on system

Tags: php, download

With the help of code given below i am able to download mail attachments to a folder on server,

```
$location="downloads/";
foreach($attachments as $attachment)
    {
        if($attachment['is_attachment'] == 1)
            {
                $filename = $attachment['name'];
                if(empty($filename)) $filename = $attachment['filename'];
                if(empty($filename)) $filename = time() . ".dat";
                $fp = fopen("$location" . $msgno . "" . $filename, "w+");
                fwrite($fp, $attachment['attachment']);
                fclose($fp);
            }

    }
```

The files that are downloaded on server through above code, i wish to download the same files on system. Can anyone please tell how i can do so

Comment: Can you expand a little on what your trying to achieve? What is 'system'? Is that the users PC?

Comment: @Trevor i have files on a folder placed on my server, from there i want to download the files on my system

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Make sure the folder that has the files is within the web server
Step 2. Add the following code to a .php file in that folder
Step 3. Modify the extension for the files you want to list at line 3 `$files = glob("*.php");`

```
<?php
    $directory = "/home/trevor/www/t/";
    $files = glob("*.php");
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        echo "<a href=$file>".basename($file)."</a><br />";
    }
?>
```